# If $\mathbb v$ denotes the velocity of a point $s$ in $\mathbb R^3$, what is $\mathbb R^3\{\mathbf v\}$? (notation)

Tags: notation, mathematical-physics

I started reading 'Mathematical Aspects of Classical and Celestial Mechanics' by Vladimir Arnold (Third Edition). In page $2$ they say that the euclidean space is denoted by $E^3$; moreover:

> The set $E^3$ is also called the *configuration space* of the point $s$. The pair $(s,\mathbf v)$ is called the state of the point, and the set $E^3\times\mathbb R^3\{\mathbf v\}$, the *phase* (or *state*) *space*.

I've never seen the notation $A\{x\}$, what does it mean?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It seems like non-standard notation.  Have you read far enough to see what context the author uses it in?  When I think of state space I think of all possible configurations the system could be in whereas the point $(s, \textbf{v})$ denotes exactly one state of the system.  Possibly $E^3 \times \mathbb{R}^3\{\textbf{v}\}$ is the collection of all possible $(s, \textbf{v})$?

Comment: @Mnifldz, yes, it seems as though that is what the author is referring to. Thanks for your opinion.